# GetFullHtmlFieldId for custom requiredif validator for custom object property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I create requridif attribute as described in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2011/02/04/conditional-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx

I have classes like this:

```
public class MainClass
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public SubClass Additional { get; set; }
}
public class SubClass
{
    [RequiredIf("Field1NotExists", false, ErrorMessage = "field 1 is required")]
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public bool Field1NotExists { get; set; }
}
```

When in view I use EditorFor:

@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Additional.Field1)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Additional.Field1NotExists)

unobtrusive client side validation work properly

But when I use TextBoxFor and CheckBoxFor

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Additional.Field1)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Additional.Field1NotExists)
```

unobtrusive client side validation doesn't work

Part of requiredif attribute:

```
private string BuildDependentPropertyId(ModelMetadata metadata, ViewContext viewContext)
        {
            string depProp = viewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(this.DependentProperty);
            var thisField = metadata.PropertyName + "_";
            if (depProp.StartsWith(thisField))
                depProp = depProp.Substring(thisField.Length);
            else
            {
                var thisFieldInMiddle = "_" + metadata.PropertyName + "_";
                if (!this.DependentProperty.Contains(thisFieldInMiddle))
                    depProp = depProp.Replace(thisFieldInMiddle, "_");
            }
            return depProp;
        }
```

When I use EditorFor ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(this.DependentProperty) return full id (Additional_Field1_Field1NotExists)

And when I use TExtBoxFor ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(this.DependentProperty) return only las field name (Field1NotExists instead of Additional_Field1NotExists)

Why ViewContext is different in this two ways? And how can I get full field id when I use TextBoxFor?

Sorry for bad English

Answer (score 0):

`TextBoxFor` and other input extensions don't persist prefixes, only editor and display extensions do. If you check the `TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix` you'll see that it's empty.

You'll also find that if you're using TextBoxFor with complex ViewModels, data won't be bound correctly when you submit for this very reason. Another reason to use Editor templates instead.